# Javascript regular expression for comma delimited decimal

Tags: javascript, regex, decimal, currency

I need a regular expression that matches currency values similar to here: [Regex for Money](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028221/regex-for-money)

i.e. '1000', '1000,0' and '1000,00'

but I need it to work using javascript:

```
 var RE = /^-{0,1}\d*\.{0,1}\d+$/; //validates decimal format such as 1000.50
    if (locale == "fr") {
        RE = \d+(?:,\d{1,2})? //this line fails when validated using the javascript below
    }
    return (RE.test(valueToValidate));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex for Money](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028221/regex-for-money) The regex posted there will be no different for javascript...

Comment: It is unclear to me what you want the regex to match and not match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Literal regex in javascript should be defined with `/` around the pattern

```
var RE = /^-{0,1}\d*\.{0,1}\d+$/; //validates decimal format such as 1000.50
if (locale == "fr") {
    RE = /\d+(?:,\d{1,2})?/ //this line fails when validated using the javascript below
}
return (RE.test(valueToValidate));
```

Comment: thanks for the heads up about the / defining the pattern when using javascript

Comment: you can also optionally append `i` and `g` after the trailing `/` to make the pattern insensitive or global respectively

Answer (score 0):

Just a syntax check: did you forget the forward slashes in your second assignment?