# manipulation string using regex using ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, string

how to regex this string in ruby?

i have sample string like this :

```
a = "$65,000 /year for 2 years"
b = "Total of $120,000 ($60,000 per annum)"
c = "$40,000.0"
```

how to get result like this using regex :

```
a = "$65,000"
b = "$120,000"
c = "$40,000"
```

how do that?

thanks before

Comment: why only `$120,000 ` and not `$60,000` in string `b`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex for Money](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028221/regex-for-money) (for the regexp part of the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for all prices within the range of $1,000 and $999,999:

```
string[/(\$\d{1,3},\d{1,3})/, 1]
```

This will also extract the right value (120,000) from your second string, since it always matches the first appearance in the string.

Comment: This will also catch `$10,11'

Answer (score 0):

You can use scan function.

```
irb(main):001:0> a = "$65,000 /year for 2 years"
=> "$65,000 /year for 2 years"
irb(main):002:0> a.scan(/\$[\d,]+/)
=> ["$65,000"]
irb(main):003:0>
```

Answer (score 0):

using this :

```
\$[^\s.]+
```

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/mS3eP6

and can be accomplished by using [**match**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html#method-i-match)

like this

```
b = "Total of $120,000 ($60,000 per annum)"
c = b.match(/\$[^\s.]+/)
c[0]

 => "$120,000"
```

This regex makes sure to select anything after `$` and before a space or a decimal point.
the match is used to capture only the first match as that is your requirement

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
\$\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*
```

It captures all valid numbers with a "," thousand's delimiter from `$1` up.
You'll get:

```
a[/\$\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*/]
# => "$65,000" 
b[/\$\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*/]
# => "$120,000" 
c[/\$\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*/]
# => "$40,000" 
"Total of $12"[/\$\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*/]
# => "$12" 
"More than $12,998,109,223"[/\$\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*/]
# => "$12,998,109,223"
```

You can also play with it [here](http://regex101.com/r/cH0pU6)

Answer (score 0):

```
a = "$65,000 /year for 2 years"
b = "Total of $120,000 ($60,000 per annum)"
c = "$40,000.0"

p a[/\$[\d,]+/] #=> "$65,000"
p b[/\$[\d,]+/] #=> "$120,000"
p c[/\$[\d,]+/] #=> "$40,000"
```