# ASP MVC 5 C# .NET Regex Annotation for price not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc

I'm using the following regex for a price but it's not forcing a valid price.

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\d+(\.\d{2})?$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid price.")]
```

It's preventing most non-price input, but it's allowing prices in the following form:

3.

21.

etc.

Why is it allowing the decimal but not requiring the two digits? What would my regex look like to force the digits if a decimal is present?

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028221/regex-for-money

Comment: Your regex is definitely valid, perhaps something else is going on in your validation. That is: `new Regex(@"^\d+(\.\d{2})?$").IsMatch("21.")` returns false.

Comment: To echo @Rob, the regex itself is working fine... http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=93554

Answer (score 0):

It is probably allowing number without decimal points because of quantifier `?` in the expression.

Quantifier `(..)` captures everything enclosed in the parens

Quantifier `?` means "zero or one of the preceding"

`()?` captures zero or one of everything enclosed in parens.

so '.'  and the two digits can appear zero or one time.

This expression should resolve issue. 
since its not enclosed and without quantifier `?`.

^\d+(.\d{2})  or    ^\d+.\d{2}$

You can use this site to help you build regular expressions.
https://regex101.com/

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer. I know why it's allowing numbers _without_ decimals - I set up the regex with that in mind. My question is, why is it allowing numbers _with_ a decimal, but without the 2 digits after the decimal?

Comment: I'm not asking why it's allowing numbers without a decimal point. I'm asking why it's allowing numbers _with_ a decimal point, even with no digits after the decimal point. I.e.: It should be allowing the following cases: "23", "2", "2.34", "213.90". Why is it allowing: "3." and "67."?

Comment: \.\d{} is not treated as one expression when '?' is applied to it. they both are two separate expressions. so the two separate expressions are optional.

this is how its read.
\.? \d? both are optional

Comment: this two are same expressions

(\.)?(\d{2})?   will allow dot(.)  to be optional and two digits  to be optional

(\.?\d{2})?     will allow dot(.)  to be optional and two digits  to be optional