# How to check if user input contains any letters by using .ToCharArray

Tags: c#, .net

*EDIT* 
I'm not allowed to use regex or (foreach) or (.IsLetter), since my class hasn't learned those yet.

I saw this question was already asked on here, but the questions were all about how to do it in Java or Python... I'm using C#.

For part of my homework, I have to validate if the user input is a money value (i.e $25.34). I've already checked if there is a '$' or a '.', but I haven't figured out how to check if they entered any letters. If they did, then it would be invalid and I would have to re-prompt them.

I tried to use `.TryParse`, but I guess that only checks if there are numbers, not letters.

My teacher gave me a hint and said to use `.ToCharArray`. I looked up how to use it on the Microsoft website, but I'm confused. This is the code on the website:

```
string str = "012wxyz789";
char[] arr;

arr = str.ToCharArray(3, 4);
Console.Write("The letters in '{0}' are: '", str);

// results:
// The letters in '012wxyz789' are: 'wxyz'
```

The problem with this is that the string is hard-coded and I need to get user input, so I won't know if there are letters or not.

How would I use `.ToCharArray` to check if there are any letters in the user input string?

(Please answer as simply as you can! I'm really new at this so I'm still learning coding jargon)

Comment: decimal.TryParse  allows you to specify a NumberStyle parameter where you can tell the parser about the Currency option

Comment: You also might need to check for negative values, either denothed as -$34.45 or ($34.45). And what about 1,000 delimiters ($34,364.34)? If allowed, check into regular expressions, like this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028221/regex-for-money

Comment: Or, if you want to follow your teacher's advice (i.e., not use Regex, etc.), you can do a `foreach` over the string (which will return back a single `char` every time through the loop).  Then check to see if the returned character is in the character set you are interested.  You'll need to create a little state machine (i.e. implement rules like "if there's a dollar sign, it must be the first character" and "there can be 0 or 1 decimal points".  I'd just skip negative numbers and 1000s separators. for now.  The `string.Contains` function is good for this kind of check

Comment: It would be helpful to clarify what correct and incorrect inputs would be. I am asking as money is a fairly broad statement (think Euros, different culture formatting, etc.). Is "123.45" acceptable as well as "$123.45" as well as "123,45" (e.g. German) as well as "123"? Note that the Parse functions are culture sensitive and default to the Invariant culture. If you are checking the stringent case of some digits, followed by a decimal followed by 2 digits with an optional $ upfront I would go with e.g. Regex.IsMatch(yourStringVariable, "^\\$?\\d+\\.\\d{2}$") otherwise I'd go with Steve's answer

Comment: As you have probably noticed, you're going to get a lot of answers on SO recommending that you use "real" features of the language.  Homework problems that come with arbitrary restrictions can be hard to answer here, since we have to guess what your teacher thinks .  It would probably be easier for you to ask *your teacher* for help than for us to try to guess what they want you to do.

Comment: Maybe you can't use `Char.IsLetter`, but `(c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')` is the same thing. `ToCharArray()`, with a string, is useless: a string is already an array of chars.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to match that :

```
^\$(0|\d+(,\d+)*)(\.\d+)?
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fT2FBv/2)

[Regular Expression Language - Quick Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference)

**C# Example :**

```
string pattern = @"^\$(0|\d+(,\d+)*)(\.\d+)?";
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);
string Data = @"$1,1225,14558.00";
Match Re = regex.Match(Data);
if(Re.Groups.Count > 1)
    Console.WriteLine("Valid Input!");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input!");
```

Comment: He's not allowed to use Regex.  :(

Too bad, they should teach all students Regex.

Comment: @ScubaSteve As long as the first thing they teach students is when *not* to use Regex.  Once you give somebody a hammer, everything looks like a nail.

Comment: For sure. I suppose string manipulation is an important skill, but yes it could be over-used. Definitely should not be used on simple manipulations, for the sake of readability.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `ToCharArray`, simply loop through the string `foreach(char c in str)` and then check each character `char.IsLetter(c)`. Something like this:

```
string str = "012wxyz789";
Console.Write("The letters in are:");
foreach (char c in str) { //same result as foreach (char c in str.ToCharArray())
    if (char.IsLetter(c))
        Console.Write(c);
}
```

If your replace `str` with `str.ToCharArray()` in the `foreach` loop above, you will get the exact same result. That's why I said `ToCharArray` was not necessary. Strings are kind of arrays of characters internally.

However, you can also do that much easier in other ways, like with regex or LINQ. More importantly, the first part of your question is a parsing matter from a string to decimal as others pointed out in the comments, so this answer is more applicable to the second part of the question as how to extract letters from a string in general.

Comment: It was specifically asked - How would I use .ToCharArray to check if there are any letters in the user input string?

Comment: @Jmyster No it wasn't asked, it was a hint. Read the question carefully. It seems the teacher wanted the students to understand that strings are arrays of characters and how to loop through them. If you replace `str` with `str.ToCharArray()` in my answer, you'll get the exact same result. That's why I said `ToCharArray` was not necessary and the students will learn the same things without it (or they will even better understand what strings are). I will update my answer to add this note.

Comment: We all know how to do things differently, maybe more efficiently. That still doesn't help when you suggest how to do thing a different way than asked. Question was still How would I use .ToCharArray to check if there are any letters in the user input string? You decided to ignore that and are adding confusion

Comment: @Jmyster I invite you to read the entire question again more carefully, not only the title. People -especially those new to SO- don't always use the best title, so the question is in the description, not title. In the description, the OP clearly mentioned that s/he unsuccessfully tried different ways (like `TryParse`) and then asked the teacher who gave her/him the hint to use `ToCharArray`. Is that clear enough to you? You need to understand the difference between hints and requirements. Hints are only there to help you, but you don't have to follow them. I didn't ignore a requirement.

Comment: I did read it and Again...it clearly states "My teacher gave me a hint and said to use .ToCharArray. I looked up how to use it on the Microsoft website, but I'm confused. This is the code on the website:" (located right before code snippet) And "How would I use .ToCharArray to check if there are any letters in the user input string?" (Located two lines after the code snippet) I don't know how you keep missing that. So offering solution outside the scope of the question/hint/title (All pointing to the same thing) will confuse MORE new SO users. It's ok to not have the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your teacher may have been hinting for you to use ToCharArray to loop through it and check if its a letter.

```
        var moneyString = "40 Thousand";

        var charArray = moneyString.ToCharArray();

        foreach (var character in charArray)
        {
            if (Char.IsLetter(character))
            {
                // Likely not acceptable
            }
        }
```

Comment: Yes, but I would go back to the teacher and say that using `ToCharArray` in that case is unnecessary in C# as you can loop through the string directly. A string is internally an array of characters.

Answer (score 0):

Now, I ain't too good at this programming stuff, but you can do some simple iteration through your string after casting it to char[] and compare it to a valid char[] list.

```
    private static bool CheckStringForNumbers(string stringToCheck)
    {
        var chars = stringToCheck.ToCharArray();
        var numbers = new char[] {'$', '.', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};

        foreach (var item in chars)
        {
            var itemIsNumber = numbers.Contains(item);
            Console.WriteLine(item + " == " + itemIsNumber);

            if (!itemIsNumber) return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

This is a pretty naive example, but the idea is that you can turn your string into a char[], and iterate through each of the char items in the array (item in the example below), and see if that item is contained within another char[] of valid items. If the item is valid (i.e. is a number in this instance), then everything is fine. But if the item is not contained within the array of valid chars, then you know the user entered something they weren't supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

Using your teachers hint, I'd go this way. Loop through your Array and TryParse will return True/false. Do what you want with it. I added NotNumbers string to hold my answer.

```
        string str = "012wxyz789";
        string NotNumbers = "";
        char[] arr;

        arr = str.ToCharArray();

        foreach (char c in arr)
        {
            int outValue;
            bool IsNumber = Int32.TryParse(c.ToString(), out outValue);
            if (IsNumber)
            {
                // Do something to number
            }
            else
            {
                // Do something to other
                // Build a string with all the non number values
                NotNumbers = NotNumbers + c.ToString();
            }
        }
```